# sorting a "key/value pair" array in bash

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, sorting

How do I sort a "python dictionary-style" array `e.g. ( "A: 2" "B: 3" "C: 1" )` in bash by the value? I think, this code snippet will make it bit more clear about my question.

```
State="Total 4 0 1 1 2 0 0"
W=$(echo $State | awk '{print $3}')
C=$(echo $State | awk '{print $4}')
U=$(echo $State | awk '{print $5}')
M=$(echo $State | awk '{print $6}')
WCUM=( "Owner: $W;" "Claimed: $C;" "Unclaimed: $U;" "Matched: $M" )
echo ${WCUM[@]}
```

This will simply print the array: `Owner: 0; Claimed: 1; Unclaimed: 1; Matched: 2`

How do I sort the array (or the output), eliminating any pair with "0" value, so that the result like this:

```
Matched: 2; Claimed: 1; Unclaimed: 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions. Cheers!!

Comment: What are you sorting on, "Matched" ?

Comment: Use python would be my advice!  IMHO you've left the sweet spot of bash.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: Obviously you don't know bash.

Comment: I think what Nick meant is: doing this kind of things in python is lot easier. Cheers!!

Comment: I would like to see what is more easy than to stick together these 4 commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty idea would be (this just sorts the output, not the array):

```
echo ${WCUM[@]} | sed -e 's/; /;\n/g' | awk -F: '!/ 0;?/ {print $0}' | sort -t: -k 2 -r | xargs
```

Comment: Thanks Michał, it worked just fine. Sorting array or output - either way works for me. All I needed to print the formatted result. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e ${WCUM[@]} | tr ';' '\n' | sort -r -k2 | egrep -v ": 0$"
```

Sorting and filtering are independent steps, so if you only like to filter 0 values, it would be much more easy.

Append an

```
 | tr '\n' ';'
```

to get it to a single line again in the end.

```
nonull=$(for n in ${!WCUM[@]}; do echo ${WCUM[n]} | egrep -v ": 0;"; done | tr -d "\n")
```

I don't see a good reason to end $W $C $U with a semicolon, but $M not, so instead of adapting my code to this distinction I would eliminate this special case. If not possible, I would append a semicolon temporary to $M and remove it in the end.

Comment: agreed on "semicolon" thing; that was the very first version and I was still deciding what to do. Thanks for the code - I actually got an idea to use this elsewhere. Just one thing: the `seq` part could be shorten like this: `${!WCUM[@]}`. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt, using some of the bash features, but still needs **sort**, that is crucial:

```
#! /bin/bash
State="Total 4 1 0 4 2 0 0"
string=$State
for i in 1 2 ; do        # remove unnecessary fields
    string=${string#* }
    string=${string% *}
done

# Insert labels
string=Owner:${string/ /;Claimed:}
string=${string/ /;Unclaimed:}
string=${string/ /;Matched:}

# Remove zeros
string=(${string[@]//;/; })
string=(${string[@]/*:0;/})
string=${string[@]}

# Format
string=${string//;/$'\n'}
string=${string//:/: }

# Sort
string=$(sort -t: -nk2 <<< "$string")
string=${string//$'\n'/;}
echo "$string"
```